# Hot to make content float over keyboard?

Tags: windows-phone-8, keyboard

I have a page witch a fixed title followed by a content and a textbox that enables the user to post to my app. When the user press the textbox the keyboard shows up and all the control slide up making impossible for the user to scroll then back?

How can I make the controls float under the keyboard so the user can scroll it.

I have tried witch grids and scrollviewers without success :(

My layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto " />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle  Width="Auto" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Rectangle Height="600" Fill="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

This is what is happening

[image: This is what is happening]

This is what i expect to happen

[image: This is what i expect to happen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article explains how to resolve the issue by manipulating the transformations done by the OS to the page.

http://klingdigital.net/2013/06/scrollviewer-and-multiline-textbox-windowsphone/

Comment: @MCAS Google cache http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7eJJ97Yr-DEJ:https://klingdigital.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/scrollviewer-and-multiline-textbox-windowsphone/+&cd=1&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br

Nothing is broken on the Internet. You just did´t know how to find it (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ edit: its a joke...

Comment: Marcelo de Aguiar, ROFLMAO.